# Dynamic pdf data populate

Tags: java, pdf

any one can you help me how to populate data into existing pdf in Java? actually i have created a dynamic pdf for student registration template .my question is any student when enter into data in jap or html GUI then it will come into existing pdf template and save .

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to accomplish is serverside form filling.

You can either use commercial products (FDFMerge by Appligent comes to my mind here), or libraries and stitch together your solutions yourself (mentioning Java, if I am not too mistaken, there is an iText Java library, for example).

Comment: THANKS , y i used itext